# How is stack used for array when stack's variable declaration is runtime?

Tags: arrays, memory-management, stack

Array's memory is allocated in compile time.
Stack uses runtime variable declaration.

**How is then stack used for array?**

Comment: There are multiple ways to implement a stack.
If the stack uses a fixed size array, it can only contain N elements. if you want to add more elements to it, you either need to reallocate the array or if you dont do it, your program will perform undefined behaviour